# golang convert os.ModePerm into string

Tags: string, go

I would like to have as a `string` the permissions representation of a file.
Here is what I want to do :

```
fileInfo, err := os.Lstat(path)
fileMode := fileInfo.Mode()
// fileMode.String() gives dturwxrwxrwx or -rwxrwxrwx
// which i do not want because the size is not always the same
unixPerms := fileMode & os.ModePerm
```

I get `-rwxrwxrwx` for both cases, which is close to what i am looking for.

However, the returned object is of type `os.FileMode`. How can I then convert it into a `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass either one of your variables, type (`os.FileMode`), as an argument to the `Sprintf` method from the [fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) package.

Leveraging this method will convert your type into a string, which can then be used as a string throughout the remainder of your program.

Example usage below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fileInfo, err := os.Lstat(path)
    if err != nil {
        // catch err
    }
    fileMode := fileInfo.Mode()
    // fileMode.String() gives dturwxrwxrwx or -rwxrwxrwx
    // which i do not want because the size is not always the same
    unixPerms := fileMode & os.ModePerm

    permString := fmt.Sprintf("%v", unixPerms)
    fmt.Println(permString)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

fileInfo.Mode().Perm().String()

https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode.Perm